# Ingress different rewrite rules for different services

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am learning Kubernetes and experimenting a bit I have the following ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: testhost-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: testhost-ingress.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/keycloak(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: keycloak
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /api/departments(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: department
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /api/employees(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: employee
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /v2(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web2
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

If I use the file above I can access department, services  and web2 services as I desired meaning if I call http://testhost-ingress.info/api/employees/add/John it will correctly call the employee service with http://employee:8080/api/employees/add/John

While this is desired for the 3 services for Keycloak I don't want the api/keycloak part being repeated http://testhost-ingress.info/api/keycloak/auth should call http://keycloak:8080/auth
If I add nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2 it will work for keycloak but now the other services won t work as expected.

How can I have different rewrite-target rules for different services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, one can uses nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet to specify some specific rules for some path. In my case for keycloak :

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* ^/api/keycloak(/|$)(.*) {
        rewrite ^/api/keycloak(/|$)(.*) /$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://keycloak.default:8080;
      }
```